# Need help deciding to transpose powershell script to python or see if the script can be refactored further. Speed issue with data

Tags: python, powershell, csv, comparison

#### Problem Summary

I have a powershell script that does what I want it to. It runs too slow. Even after I refactored my code. It's going through 20,000 objects, doing comparisons, and I'm using an empty list to create new objects from the comparisons. I did everything I researched to speed everything up. It worked. It's still not fast enough.

#### What the script does: Generates an Excel Report

#### How the script works:

#### Collects Data

- Collects 2 Data Sets (Set1, Set2)
- Transforms the data in Set1 so that it can be compared with Set2. It just adds two properties to each object in the data set.
- From here the data sets are stored in seperate variables. (Set1Raw, Set2Raw)
- The data sets are each individually filtered and then stored in seperate variables (Set1Filtered, Set2Filtered)

#### Does Data Comparisons and creates new object from comparison

- Creates empty list variable for final results
- Compare Set1Filtered to Set2Raw [foreach($entry in Set2Raw)

  - Creates a variable that will first make sure we are dealing with the same CompName
  - Creates a a new object with the properties I want
  - One property does an if logic statement
  - Outputs object to the list
- Compare Set2Filtered to Set1Raw (same logic but with corrected variables
- if property named status is "No Match" user wants to combine with 1st one and de-duplicate

I've refactored my powershell code and it's taking too long to generate the list. I've changed to $variable.foreach() on what I can, and as well as $variable.where(). On top of that I did inline objects that are faster too. All of this helped improve the speed. I couldn't take one foreach out or replace it though and I'm wondering if it's something I didn't research enough on my end. If I can't refactor this, I want to convert the part that's slow over to python. I an export the vars as csvs and call the python script to do the rest.

```
GatherDataWithParallelJobs -Set1JobName "GatherSet1Data" -Set2JobName "GatherSet2Data"
$Set1Raw = Receive-Job "GatherSet1Data" -keep 
$Set2Raw = Receive-Job "GatherSet2Data" -keep
$Set1Filtered = $Set1Raw.where({$_.event_id -eq 1 -or $_.event_id -eq 2 -or $_.event_id -eq 3 -or $_.event_id -eq 4 -or $_.event_id -eq 5 -or $_.event_id -eq 6 -or $_.event_id -eq 7 -or $_.event_id -eq 10 -or $_.event_id -eq 14 -or $_.event_id -eq 16})
$Set2Filtered = $Set2Raw.where({$_.event_id -ne 1 -and $_.event_id -ne 11 -and $_.event_id -ne 13 -and $_.WormGroupName -notlike "*Unix*"})


function GenerateReport-Set1FilteredComparedToSet2Raw {

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$list = @()

foreach($entry in $Set2Raw) {
# make sure we are dealing with the SAME CompName
    $SameComp = $Set1Filtered.Where({$_.CompName -eq $entry.CompName}) | Select-Object -Property event_id -first 1 -ExpandProperty event_id 
    $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
        CompName = $entry.CompName
        FilteredTanium_event_id = $SameComp."event_id"
        UnfilteredWORM_event_id = $entry."event_id"
        Status = if($entry."event_id" -eq $SameComp."event_id"){"Match"}elseif(($entry."event_id") -and ($SameComp."event_id") -and $entry."event_id" -ne $SameComp."event_id"){"No Match"}elseif(-Not($entry."event_id") -and ($SameComp."event_id")){"Set2 Only"}elseif(($entry."event_id") -and -not($SameComp."event_id")){"Set1 Only"}else{"No Match"}
    }
    $list += $result
}
$list
}

$set1FComparedToSet2R = GenerateReport-Set1FilteredComparedToSet2Raw  
$set2FComparedToSet1R = GenerateReport-Set2FilteredComparedToSet1Raw

$set1Raw | Export-Excel -Path $Path -WorksheetName "Set1Raw"
$set2Raw | Export-Excel -Path $Path -WorksheetName "Set2Raw"

$set1FComparedToSet2R.where($status -eq "Match")| Export-Excel -Path $Path -WorksheetName "Match"

$set1FComparedToSet2R.where($status -eq "Set1 Only")| Export-Excel -Path $Path -WorksheetName "Set1 Only"

$set1FComparedToSet2R.where($status -eq "No Match")| Export-Excel -Path $Path -WorksheetName "No Match"


$set2FComparedToSet1R.where($staus -eq "No Match")| Export-Excel -Path $Path -WorksheetName "No Math" -Append

DeDuplicate
```

I only included the code necessary. This is it.

#### Expectations

I just need to know which way I should go to fix this. Fix the powershell or use Python.

Is there a way for that foreach method to go faster? I know how to do the $variable.foreach() to increase speed, but how would I do it without a var?

Would this be faster in python? How should I go about it if I do?

Comment: If you are more comfortable with Python you should take that route. If you with to continue to use PowerShell I recommend using generic lists `[System.Collections.Generic.List[T]]` over an `ArrayList`. For example, adding 20000 ints to an empty `ArrayList` takes about 24 seconds in PowerShell while it takes only 210 milliseconds with a `List[T]`.

Comment: Aside from that, do you know what part of the code is slow?

Comment: Could you provide your input files for testing? I would use integrated c# code for time critical jobs in PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I did a measure command and the foreach loop is worst. I haven't measure the speed inside the loop itself but each individual piece is quick when I do testing outside the loop.

Comment: Haven't tested, but I think using `$list.Add($result)` is faster than `$list += $result`. As an aside, you can shorten the code for `$Set1Filtered` to `$Set1Filtered = $Set1Raw.where({@((1..7) + (10,14,16)) -contains $_.event_id})` and the one for `$Set2Filtered` to `$Set2Filtered = $Set2Raw.where({@(1,11,13) -notcontains $_.event_id -and $_.WormGroupName -notlike "*Unix*"})`